# Using MemberQ or Contains* in a query fails

Tags: databaselink, sql

Using MemberQ or Contains* in a query fails:

```
DatabaseLink`SQL`Private`SQLValue::illegalvalue: The value ContainsAny[SQLColumn[{photos, tweet_id}],{576909568741138432, 576909575019859969, 576909578362712065}] cannot be converted to a value in an SQL statement.
```

Is there any elegant way around this?